# Convert NSString into 6bit binary representation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, binary

I want to convert a `NSString` into 6 bit binary.

For Example :

Input:

```
NSString = @"A";
```

Output:

```
010001
```

Comment: In binary 010001 will be equivalent to 17 in decimal system. What is the mapping for the character values you are using? Is it some standard convention or your own representation? What is it?

Comment: actually.. output should be in 6 bit binary for any character. this is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

```
-(void)hexadecimal_change:(NSString *)string{
NSLog(@"hexa");

NSString *hex = string;
NSUInteger hexAsInt;
[[NSScanner scannerWithString:hex] scanHexInt:&hexAsInt];
NSString *binary = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self toBinary:hexAsInt]];
NSLog(@"%@",binary);

long v = strtol([binary1 UTF8String], NULL, 2);
NSString *dec=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",v];
NSLog(@"%@",dec); 



}



 -(NSString *)toBinary:(NSUInteger)input{
    if (input == 1 || input == 0)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", input];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%u", [self toBinary:input / 2], input % 2];
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thinks.. It's work properly but  for string 'A'  this method print binary as '1011' which is not 6 bit binary.